# problema al acceder a variables publica - angular8 tabulator4.2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Utilizando
-Angular 8
-Tabulator 4.2

Tengo una variable de actividades que es un arreglo, a este arreglo le ingrese unos elementos en el constructor pero cuando quiero acceder a la variable me muestra ***undefined***

Me pueden apoyar, como puedo acceder a esta variable ¿?
ya sea para leer o agregar datos al arreglo.

La tabla se me muestra correctamente pero al darle doble click que es el evento, este muestra el valor ***undefined***

Componente

[image: Componente]

[image: Mensaje de Error]

[image: Linea de Error]

[Tabulator Angular](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/frameworks#angular)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta:

```
public deleteItem(){
    console.log("Mostrando listado de actividades");
    console.log(this.arr_actividades);
}

public deleteRow(losParametrosQueHabian){
   //Lo que había
}
```

Puede ser que los métodos no tengan el mismo scope si los añades así como lo hiciste, talvez por eso falle, puede que this no sea la instancia de la clase si no la clase en si o alguna cosa extraña o que ya de por sí pierda su contexto.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para la respuesta me apoye en el foro en ingles donde indican lo siguiente

ES6 introduce `lambda` tambien llamado `arrow function`, por lo que quedaria asi la llamada a la funcion que uno quiere.

```
cellClick: (e, row)=> this.openDialog(e, row)
```

[Enlace de la respuesta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500906/tabulator-cell-click-how-to-call-a-function-in-angular-on-cell-click-and-use-co/61760007#61760007)